# General term for something real as opposed to digital/virtual?

Tags: nouns, terminology

I'm looking for a term that encompasses physical objects, people, processes. Basically everything from the real world as opposed to the digital. I have considered *entity*, but I am not sure, whether it fits the bill. Also I would need an attribute to differentiate it from digital things like software.

My context is general modelling. Intended usage would be: A model is a representation of ...

Comment: Is there a reason why "real world object" won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of objects and people, something that is in the so-called real world is [**corporeal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corporeal):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : having, consisting of, or relating to a physical material body: such as
>
> **a** : not spiritual
> // … some few traces of a diviner nature which look out through his *corporeal* baseness …
> — Robert Browning
>
> **b** : not immaterial or intangible : SUBSTANTIAL
> // *corporeal* property

So:

> A model is a representation of one or more *corporeal* objects.

---

But you may not be able to distinguish a *virtual* process from a *real* process. Since processes are ideas, they exist outside of anything physical (*corporeal*), and so have existence in both realms: the virtual and the material. (Note that *material* is a viable alternative to *corporeal*.)

In short, an idea that's been expressed on a piece of paper, but not enacted anywhere, has just as much reality as an idea that's expressed in a game, but not enacted anywhere. In fact, if the idea *is* actually enacted in a game, it may be thought of to actually be *more* real than the same idea simply written down on a piece of paper in the corporeal world.

I don't think you're going to be able to come up with a word that applies to processes (or ideas) in the same way as one that will apply to physical objects and beings. Discussion of that would be better suited to the [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Your second paragraph brings back memories of Anselm's Ontological Proof of the Existence of God.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think the distinction between _virtual_ and _real_ processes threw me off. Your reference to Philosophy.SE helped me look at the problem in a new way. I need to model business processes. In my context there is a difference between the process of printing forms and sending letters, making phone calls, etc. as opposed to  everything being digital and automated. This way the the material actions differ, but the function or idea of the process stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Realty - I reference the original etymology, not just home/housing/land real estate.

[https://www.etymonline.com/word/realty#:~:text=early%2014c.%2C%20%22actually%20existing,%2Di%2D%20%22wealth.%22](https://www.etymonline.com/word/realty#:%7E:text=early%2014c.%2C%20%22actually%20existing,%2Di%2D%20%22wealth.%22)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

A general term opposed to **digital** is **analog**.

> **analog** ADJECTIVE
>   1.2 Not involving or relating to the use of computer technology, as a contrast to a digital counterpart.
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/analog)

But it would be interesting to find a term opposed to **virtual**

[Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/virtual) has this:

> Antonyms for **virtual**
>   actual  authentic  real

There is a considerable body of science fiction nowadays involving both virtual and non-virtual.  Maybe this is a reasonable question to ask in https://scifi.stackexchange.com

Comment: But *analog* is not a general purpose antonym for *digital*; such usage is confined to a few domains, including *analog electronics* and *analog computers* (yes, whatever Lexico says *analog computers* are a real thing).